# Is there a way to remap the AltGr key to Ctrl with setxkbmap?

Tags: xorg, x11, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, xkb

I've already checked the option section in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst` but I didn't find an entry for <kbd>AltGr</kbd>...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestions of the Xorg community I found out the correct setxkbmap command:

```
setxkbmap -option ctrl:ralt_rctrl
```

Answer (score 2):

Surely, you can achieve this by editing the xkb rules set but it might be more convenient to use `xmodmap`.

You can use `xev` to lookup the keycode of your <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key. On my system it also has the name <kbd>ISO_Level3_Shift</kbd> which is already used for the modifier <kbd>mod5</kbd> (use `xmodmap` to see the modifier maps). Removing it from <kbd>mod5</kbd> and adding it to the <kbd>control</kbd>  modifier makes the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key work like the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>:
`xmodmap -e "remove mod5 = ISO_Level3_Shift"; xmodmap -e "c
add control = ISO_Level3_Shift"`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However the reason I asked for setxkbmap is because some xmodmap entries on my /.xsesssionrc seem to be ignored at system startup, and they don't take effect. How can I edit the xkb rules to achieve the same effect? Thanks again.

Comment: Anyway thanks antje-m. I'm going to +1 your answer when I'll get 15+ rep!

Comment: Thank you.
You mentioned that some xmodmap in .xsessionrc get ignored. Have you considered that your desktop environment might set some keyboard options that override yours? I know you didn't ask, but the thought just crossed my mind.

Comment: xmodmap is ancient and superseeded by xkbd tools.