# How to swap Left Alt with Right Alt

Tags: x11, xorg, xkb, xmodmap

How to swap the keys and make Left <kbd>Alt</kbd> act like <kbd>AltGr</kbd> as well? I tried `xmodmap` with the following:

```
clear mod1
clear mod5
keycode 108 = Alt_L Meta_L
keycode 64 = Alt_R Meta_R
add mod1 = ISO_Level3_Shift
add mod5 = Alt_L Meta_L
```

but it doesn't work. Output from `xev` when I hit left <kbd>Alt</kbd> is

```
KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0xb000001,
    root 0x1e0, subw 0x0, time 70149128, (43,110), root:(3464,565),
    state 0x18, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
```

And for right <kbd>Alt</kbd> is

```
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0xb000001,
    root 0x1e0, subw 0x0, time 70149484, (43,110), root:(3464,565),
    state 0x10, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
```

I saw people try using `ISO_Level3_Shift`: [Is there a way to remap the AltGr key to Ctrl with setxkbmap?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32606/is-there-a-way-to-remap-the-altgr-key-to-ctrl-with-setxkbmap) and `xmodmap`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/93624/how-do-i-swap-left-ctrl-with-left-alt-on-my-keyboard but it's not enough. The documentation of `xmodmap` sucks.

Comment: I did `keycode 64 = ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift ISO_Level3_Shift
keycode 108 = Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L` and it maybe works. Can someone explain it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [`man xkeyboard-config`, **Key to choose the 3rd level**](https://man.openbsd.org/xkeyboard-config#Key_to_choose_3rd_level), several options are listed to modify access to the 3rd level.

```
lv3:alt_switch             Any Alt
lv3:lalt_switch            Left Alt
lv3:ralt_switch            Right Alt
lv3:ralt_switch_multikey   Right Alt; Shift+Right Alt as Compose
lv3:ralt_alt               Right Alt never chooses 3rd level
```

Thus

```
setxkbmap -option lv3:lalt_switch -option lv3:ralt_alt
```

makes the left Alt access 3rd level and right Alt an ordinary Alt.

Put the command in a start-up script to make it persistent, or in Debian based systems include the options in [`/etc/default/keyboard`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/keyboard-configuration/keyboard.5.en.html):

```
XKBOPTIONS="lv3:lalt_switch,lv3:ralt_alt"
```